# FTP connection without proxy

Tags: java, proxy, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have a system, where we were sending files by FTP transfer through Proxy.
Now i need to make a change to send the files with or without Proxy.

I tried just creating an `FTPClient` connection without host and port values and also without user id and pwd. like `client = new FtpClient();`

Alone this makes sending the files without Proxy?

I read about `Proxy.Type.DIRECT`, not understanding the usage of that whether i should apply for my requirement.

Comment: What language is that? What `FtpClient` class is that (what library)? Show us your current code with proxy.

Comment: Hi @Martin Prikryl , Its in Java language.A FTP client is a software which uses the FTP protocol to transfer files to and from a remote computer. Advertisements: FTP is the most widespread transfer protocol used to transfer files from one host to another over the Internet.     client = new FtpClient(proxy, Integer.parseInt(port));
          client.login(username+"@"+host, password);

Comment: 1) I know what FTP client is. I'm asking what FTP client library are you using? Apache Commons? 2) Include your code into the question (use "edit" link below the post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, it seems that you are using an FTP proxy (not a normal proxy).

```
client = new FtpClient(proxy, Integer.parseInt(port));  
client.login(username+"@"+host, password);
```

If you want to connect directly, connect to the `host`, not `proxy`. Also I assume that the actual username of the target host is just a `username`. The FTP proxy uses a username in format `username@host` to tell, what host it should forward the connection to.

```
client = new FtpClient(host, Integer.parseInt(port));  
client.login(username, password);
```

Not sure about the port. If your FTP proxy uses a non-standard port, you probably should not use the `port`, but connect to a standard FTP port `21`.

Comment: ,Yes apache commons was being used. i will try to consider your suggestions going forward. Here the Port is by default set to 80 initially. So i will include the same.

Comment: can you please explain what makes the difference

Comment: it has been mentioned like if(port == null)
            port = "80";

Comment: FTP servers listen on port 21. 80 is used used by HTTP (web) servers. And sometimes by proxy servers.